# SQL Query for Golf Score Leaderboard

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm querying a MySQL table using the Wordpress plugin Create SQL Report. I'm not familiar with SQL but I'm looking to query a table that has multiple entries from the same users. I need to separate the users by students and teachers, aggregate the totals of five categories individually by user, and develop a leaderboard for students and one for teachers.  The leaders are based on a golf score that's calculated by ranking the user in each of the five categories and sorting in ascending order based on combined score (from adding the rankings).

All the fields I've mentioned (User, Role-Student or Teacher, and the five Categories) are all values in the table's column called field_name and need to be pivoted to headers. The values associated for each field are under the column field_value, and a third column names the form it comes from (Numbers):

```
form_name          field_name         field_value
numbers            user               a
numbers            role               student
numbers            category1          4
numbers            category2          9
numbers            category3          7
numbers            category4          3
numbers            category5          2
numbers            user               b
numbers            role               student
numbers            category1          7
numbers            category2          5
numbers            category3          8
numbers            category4          2
numbers            category5          9
numbers            user               a
numbers            role               student
numbers            category1          2
numbers            category2          6
numbers            category3          1
numbers            category4          8
numbers            category5          8
numbers            user               c
numbers            role               teacher
numbers            category1          2
numbers            category2          11
numbers            category3          3
numbers            category4          8
numbers            category5          5
numbers            user               d
numbers            role               teacher
numbers            category1          1
numbers            category2          13
numbers            category3          6
numbers            category4          8
numbers            category5          7
```

There's an indeterminate number of users. The output should list the username, aggregate sum of each category, rank in each category, and final rank. It doesn't need to display the role (as student or teacher since I'll put the students' leaderboard on one page and the teachers' on another), the form name, or the golf score (from adding up all the individual category rankings. I.e.:

```
user c1 c1r c2 c2r c3 c3r c4 c4r c5 c5r golf overall form    role 
a    6  2   14 1   8  1   11 1   10 1   6    1       numbers student 
b    7  1   5  2   8  1   2  2   9  2   8    2       numbers student
```

A second, but similar query will pull the teachers numbers:

```
user c1 c1r c2 c2r c3 c3r c4 c4r c5 c5r golf overall form    role 
d    1  2   13 1   6  1   8  1   7  1   6    1       numbers teacher     
c    2  1   11 2   3  2   8  1   5  2   8    2       numbers teacher
```

c1 = category1,
c1r= category1 rank

The golf score, form and role columns should be hidden.

Anyone have an idea how to put this into a query? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the table(s) structure(s) please?

Comment: Table structures added to question. Any advice? Thanks

Comment: This data barely has any structure and this is not a typical SQL question on top of the fact that MySQL is already limited in many of the features that are useful for working on this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to drop the data into a table with an identity column and assume that the rows would be added sequentially. Unless there a column you left out there's just no way to do it as it. You should be able to use SQL Fiddle if you don't have access to SQL Server anywhere else.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/751d4/33)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
create table T (id int not null identity, nm varchar(20), val varchar(20));
insert into T (nm, val) values
    ('user', 'a'),
    ('role', 'student'),
    ('category1', '4'),
    ('category2', '9'),
    ('category3', '7'),
    ('category4', '3'),
    ('category5', '2'),
    ('user', 'b'),
    ('role', 'student'),
    ('category1', '7'),
    ('category2', '5'),
    ('category3', '8'),
    ('category4', '2'),
    ('category5', '9'),
    ('user', 'a'),
    ('role', 'student'),
    ('category1', '2'),
    ('category2', '6'),
    ('category3', '1'),
    ('category4', '8'),
    ('category5', '8'),
    ('user', 'c'),
    ('role', 'teacher'),
    ('category1', '2'),
    ('category2', '11'),
    ('category3', '3'),
    ('category4', '8'),
    ('category5', '5'),
    ('user', 'd'),
    ('role', 'teacher'),
    ('category1', '1'),
    ('category2', '13'),
    ('category3', '6'),
    ('category4', '8'),
    ('category5', '7')
```

**Query 1**:

```
with u0(id, name) as (
    select id, val from T where nm = 'user'
),
users(id, [user], [role]) as (
    select u.id, u.name, r.val
    from u0 as u inner join T as r on r.id = u.id + 1 and r.nm = 'role'
),
scores([user], c1, c2, c3, c4, c5) as (
    select
        [user],
        sum(case when category = 'category1' then score end),
        sum(case when category = 'category2' then score end),
        sum(case when category = 'category3' then score end),
        sum(case when category = 'category4' then score end),
        sum(case when category = 'category5' then score end)
    from (
        select
            nm as category, cast(val as int) as score,
            (
                select [user] from users where id = (
                    select max(u.id) from u0 as u where u.id < s.id
                )
            ) as [user]
        from T as s
        where nm like 'category_'
        ) as s_pivot
    group by [user]
)
select
    u.[role], u.[user],
    c1, rank() over (partition by u.[role] order by c1 desc) as c1r,
    c2, rank() over (partition by u.[role] order by c2 desc) as c2r,
    c3, rank() over (partition by u.[role] order by c3 desc) as c3r,
    c4, rank() over (partition by u.[role] order by c4 desc) as c4r,
    c5, rank() over (partition by u.[role] order by c5 desc) as c5r,
    rank() over (partition by u.[role] order by c1+c2+c3+c4+c5 desc) as overall
from
    (select distinct [user], [role] from users) as u
    inner join scores as s on s.[user] = u.[user]
order by
    u.[role], u.[user]
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/751d4/33/0)**:

```
|    ROLE | USER | C1 | C1R | C2 | C2R | C3 | C3R | C4 | C4R | C5 | C5R | OVERALL |
|---------|------|----|-----|----|-----|----|-----|----|-----|----|-----|---------|
| student |    a |  6 |   2 | 15 |   1 |  8 |   1 | 11 |   1 | 10 |   1 |       1 |
| student |    b |  7 |   1 |  5 |   2 |  8 |   1 |  2 |   2 |  9 |   2 |       2 |
| teacher |    c |  2 |   1 | 11 |   2 |  3 |   2 |  8 |   1 |  5 |   2 |       2 |
| teacher |    d |  1 |   2 | 13 |   1 |  6 |   1 |  8 |   1 |  7 |   1 |       1 |
```

Here's a query that will let you easily create a script to transfer the data to another server:

```
select 'insert into T (nm, val) values (''' + field_name + ''', ''' + field_value + ''')'
from ??
```

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. I'm getting an error on the first line with u0. My table doesn't have a traditional Auto Incr id column, it has a submit_time column with seconds going out 4 decimals acting as the primary key. I've tried adding an id but can't get it to connect to all the associated fields within field_name like the submit_time does. So I've substituted submit_time in for id in your solution. Is that causing the u0 error?

Comment: The substitution might work but you're still not going to be able to use my version on MySQL which doesn't support CTEs (WITH) or even the rank function. I'm not saying it's impossible but I wasn't ready to take up that challenge since my knowledge of MySQL specifics is fairly limited.

Comment: Actually if you did substitute submit_time for _every_ occurrence of id then it might (probably would) cause problems. I think only the one inside the u0 query need to be changed to `select submit_time, val ...`

Comment: And `submit_time` must be unique across all rows. And now I just realized that my lookup of the role assumed that the role would have an id equal to the id of the user name plus one.